# Default code-prettify highlighting for C# is incorrect

Tags: bug, tags, syntax-highlighting, editor

Recently I had quite a few edits to include the correct syntax-highlighting for C# questions:

```
<!-- language: lang-csharp -->
```

That's needless editing for a thing that could also be done via machine.

I suggest defaulting to lang-csharp for questions asked with [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23).

**Update:**

Example question:

- [Solving for the zero of an arbitrary function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60027/solving-for-the-zero-of-an-arbitrary-function)

The above question highlights differently with `lang-cs` vs. `lang-csharp` (with `lang-csharp` being superior).

Issues:

1. `lang-csharp` is [not documented to exist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/241497)
2. it is not available in [the tag-wiki syntax editor](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/tags/c%23/info)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked into what does the SE version of [prettify.js](https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Js/prettify-full.en.js?v=cda74e047929) actually do. Turns out, its list of C# keywords starts like this (only with minified names):

```
var CSHARP_KEYWORDS = [JAVA_KEYWORDS,
  "as,base,by,checked,decimal,delegate,descending,dynamic,event," + …
```

This list is from [an old version of prettify](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/js-modules/prettify.js?spec=svn305&r=270#110), [the current version](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/browse/trunk/js-modules/prettify.js#110) starts like this ([the relevant change](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/diff?spec=svn305&old=292&r=303&format=unidiff&path=%2Ftrunk%2Fjs-modules%2Fprettify.js) was made [in June 2013](https://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/source/detail?spec=svn305&r=303)):

```
var CSHARP_KEYWORDS = [COMMON_KEYWORDS,
  "abstract,as,base,bool,by,byte,checked,decimal,delegate,descending," + …
```

The reason why `lang-csharp` looks like it works, is because that's considered an unknown language and so it uses `ALL_KEYWORDS`, which includes `bool` through `CPP_KEYWORDS`. This also means that something like `lang-nonsense` would have worked the same way.

The fix should be to make SE update prettify to its current version.

Comment: Thanks - [and forwarded/noted](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/2270/default-code-prettify-highlighting-for-c-is-incorrect/2279#comment5872_2271)

Answer (score 0):

`lang-csharp` is not available as a syntax for tags:

[image]

The current language for [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) is `lang-cs` which is.... [from here:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/241497) **C#** ...

Are you sure you have the syntax right?

---

**UPDATE:**

Example question:

- [Solving for the zero of an arbitrary function](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60027/solving-for-the-zero-of-an-arbitrary-function)

The above question highlights differently with `lang-cs` vs. `lang-csharp` (with `lang-csharp` being superior).

Issues:

1. `lang-csharp` is not documented to exist
2. it is not available in the tag-wiki syntax editor

Comment: relatively sure. For one I know that the current default syntax highlight doesn't go for `bool`, but `lang-csharp` does.

Comment: For the record I edited [this question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60027/solving-for-the-zero-of-an-arbitrary-function)

Comment: The code highlighter is set to the "default" on all posts - if there is an override, it will use that (if it can't recognize a valid override). Which is a heuristic best effort highlight.

Comment: @Oded - FYI: http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/2279/31503 - lang-cs is out of date

Comment: @rolfl - thanks for that. Will look getting it updated.

Comment: @rolfl - latest release is from March 2013 and is the one we are using. The changes highlighted are from June 2013 and have seen no release... yet.